# php,pdo,foreach

Tags: foreach, pdo

Code:

```
public static function selectlogin($sq)
{       
    $db_handler = self::handler();

    $res = $db_handler->query($sq);


    foreach ($res as $row)
    {
        $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $row['id'];
    }

    return $_SESSION['admin_id'];
}
```

Error Message

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Can anybody fix this?

Comment: Try `print_r($res)` after your `query` call.  It's possible that the query is failing and thus you can't get the results.

Comment: @mahi Can you add the handler::query source to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am *not aware of the *library* that you are using, but before the foreach, you have to use same kind of equivalent of [**mysql_fetch_array()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to convert the SQL Result Resource into an array which you can than work on. The reason for the error is because **$res** contains a Result Resource, not the result itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! ... Your $res is a falsy value. NULL or FALSE.

```
if ($res)
{
  for ($res as $row)
  {
    $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $row['id'];
  }
  return $_SESSION['admin_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
if (is_array($res))
{
     foreach ($res as $row)
    {
     // store
    }
}
```

We check if array is not empty. and this way its cleaner.

Comment: I believe that the problem is different. Do you think that he had converted the Result Resource into an array?

Comment: yes i think.because as of now we cant see if he converted it into a array. if only we can see the other code before it.

Answer (score 0):

> PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure

`var_dump($res);` what is output?